# Small axes, 3D vector graph - rotation of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, rotating

Would anyone know how to rotate the Z2 arrow by 90 degrees in order achieve the the Z2 arrow in blue? The plot only shows the small axes which functions as descriptions of the functions within a 3D vector graph.

[image: rotation of Z2 arrow in blue]

The code I have created is the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{physics}
\tikzset{>=latex} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}


\colorlet{vcol}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{Hcol}{blue!90!white!80}

\colorlet{Scol}{red!85!red!85!black!90}
\def\tick#1#2{\draw[thick] (#1) ++ (#2:0.2) --++ (#2-180:0.4)}


\colorlet{vcol}{blue!50!black}
\colorlet{Hcol}{red!40!white!80}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-15:0.9), y=(90:0.9), z=(-155:1.1),
                    line cap=round, line join=round,
                    axis/.style={black, thick,->},
                    vector/.style={>=stealth,->},
                    system/.style={below,align=center,scale=0.73}] 
  \large
  \def\A{1.5}                  % amplitude
  \def\nNodes{5}               % use even number
  \def\nVectorsPerNode{8}      % number of vectors per node
  \def\omeg{1.5}               % angular frequency
  \def\xmax{\nNodes*pi/\omeg*1.15}
  \def\ymax{1.8*\A}
  \def\zmax{1.8*\A}
  
  \def\quart{pi/2/\omeg}       % quarter wavelength for origin shift
  \pgfmathsetmacro\nVectors{(\nVectorsPerNode+1)*\nNodes}
  

 \def\xOffset{{(\nNodes-1)*pi/2}}
  \def\yOffset{\A*1.2}
  \def\zOffset{\A*2.2}
  \draw[axis, ->, black] (\xOffset,\yOffset,-\zOffset, -\yOffset) -- ++(\A*1.6,0,0,0) node[right,align=center]{x}; 
  
\draw[axis, ->, blue!90!white!80]  (\xOffset,\yOffset,-\zOffset, -\yOffset) -- ++(0,\A*0.6,0,0) node[right] {Z2};
    
  \draw[axis, ->, red!85!red!85!black!90]   (\xOffset,\yOffset,-\zOffset, -\yOffset) -- ++(0,0,\A*0.6,0) node[above left] {Z1};
  
 \draw[dashed, ->, black!90]   (\xOffset,\yOffset,-\zOffset, -\yOffset) -- ++(-90:1.2) node[right,align=center]{AAAA};
 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `\draw[axis, ->, blue!90!white!80]  (\xOffset,\yOffset,-\zOffset, -\yOffset) -- ++(\A*1.2,\A*0.6,\A*0.6,\A*0.6) node[right] {Z2};`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. 

Regarding the "Z2" label in blue, is there any possibility to posit it at the left hand side of the arrow? I already tried it by changing node[above right] to node[above left]. Now, the label appears directly on the arrow.

Comment: Your welcome. For labeling, I think `[above=1.5mm, left=1mm]` is sufficient. You can change the values.

Comment: This works, perfect. Thank you so much!